# whites-space: nowrap not applied on safari v 16.3 and abov

Tags: html, css, material-ui, safari, nowrap

```
    <Box
      fontWeight="bold"
      display="inline"
      component="span"
      whiteSpace="noWrap"
    >
      {nodeImageUrl && (
        <img
          className={classes.nodeHightLightImage}
          alt="List description node"
          src={nodeImageUrl}
        />
      )}
      <Box component="span" whiteSpace="pre-wrap">
        {value}
      </Box>
    </Box>
```

On safari Version 14.1.1, the `noWrap` is working as expected that means it won't display the icon and the text in a separate line. But on safari version 16.3 and above the `noWrap` style don't have any effect and it renders the img around end of line and start the text in a new line like,

[image]

But on Safari version 14.1.1, it's displayed like,
[image]

What I would like to achieve is, I don't want the icon to be displayed in its own line, instead I want it to be displayed with the text, but the text it can wrap.

Comment: Open up your developer tools and inspect the elements in question. See if it's there, see if it's being overridden, etc.

Comment: I saw that, and it does exist without being overriden.

Comment: Can you share reduction (Test case) or URL, where this is happening, so we can test it in Safari Technology Preview or WebKit builds and if needed, raise bug as well?